# If the connection string is encrypted in the web.config is the site accessible by outside users?

Tags: c#, asp.net, encryption, web-config, connection-string

I want to encrypt my connection string in my web.config.

1. What's the best way to do that?

2. Will that cause a problem to access the site by out side users.

3. If so, what can be done so users will be able to access the site? (Users enter by username and password).

Thank you.

Comment: why do you want to encrypt the connectionstring in the web.config?

Comment: What do you mean by 'out side users'?

Comment: @FlorisPrijt - It's a best practice. It means that a directory traversal attack or other server breach will not expose the credentials for your SQL server. Defence in depth.

Comment: @Wolfwyrd - Ah I get it now, if you look from that side it does make sense. Thanks

Comment: @ dtryon The site is not on an internal network but open to workers connecting from the web in order to manage their account.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Encrypting the connection string in web.config file in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2460911/encrypting-the-connection-string-in-web-config-file-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encrypting your connection string will have no effect on other users logging into your site (it is just the credentials that your app uses to connect to the database). The .Net SDK bundles tools to protect your connection strings and other areas of your config file. A full overview is [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53tyfkaw.aspx).

The basic command line for this is using aspnet_regiis like this:

```
aspnet_regiis -pe "connectionStrings" -app "/SampleApplication" -prov "RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider"
```

where "connectionStrings" is the section to protect, "/SampleApplication" is your app and "RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider" is the provider to use to protect it.

Q3 is moot, it wont affect your users.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, such a site will be accessible.

Encrypting the connection string has nothing to do with how accessible the site is.

1. Use `aspnet_regiis` with the encryption options. I suggest this [howto](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998283.aspx) for details.
2. Shouldn't cause problems.
3. Just the usual things you need to do for letting users to access the site. Nothing special is required.